# Can there be a WRITE-ONLY SD card or USB stick - Can only be read with password, but written as standard drive

Tags: security, permissions, sd-card

I have seen questions about read only and write protected SD card and USB drives.
However I am asking the opposite. A drive that can be written with no special driver or modification, but requires a password for reading.

Some Operating systems are able to enforce this, having read and write permission set separately.
The goal is to use an existing OS or device without modification.

I haven't come across any such product.

1. Is it even possible to implement?
2. As suggested, does it depend on a specific filesystem.

I have a scanner with a USB connected to it, to scan and discard of sensitive documents. I wand to leave it inside the scanner and back it up once in a while. But I`m concerned leaving the USB drive for all to take or read.

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: In practice this would allow you to freely write to like `/dev/sdc`, but not to a filesystem within. To mount a filesystem you have to read some parts of it.

Comment: @gronostaj, I added your point to the question now.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, Is it even possible to Implement this on the drive, without modifying the OS.

Comment: Encrypted SD cards do exist, but I don't see how the scanner can supply the password to unlock it.

Comment: @harrymc I want writing to be without a password.

Comment: usb drives with a physical write protect switch exist https://www.kanguru.com/collections/kanguru-usb-drives-with-a-physical-write-protect-switch

Comment: What you want is possible but not as a file-system: The "password only for read" can be achieved by using asymmetric cryptography, e.g. GnuPG. Think of it as a mailbox where every body can send encrypted mails/data to (write without password) but for read you need the password to decrypt the private key that is necessary to decrypt the stored data. If you combine that with a write-once data store then you have what you want.

Comment: If a cloud storage rather than USB/SD device is an option, an FTP server or Dropbox will allow you to create a way to upload but not view files or even directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You have a piece of paper with something already written on it and you want to write some more. But you're not allowed to look at the paper to check which parts are blank. It's not possible.

---

Storage device is a bunch of addressable bytes. It doesn't know what a file is. All it can do is tell you the value of a particular byte, or set the value of a particular byte.

On top of this dumb storage we're implementing various *filesystems* like FAT32, NTFS etc. This is where the concept of files comes into existence. Filesystem is a data structure that adheres to some rules. You have to know these rules to read or write stuff - otherwise you don't know what the bytes mean or even which bytes are meaningful (is this byte a part of file contents? file name? FS structure? unused disk space?).

If you know the rules and can read the bytes, you can read files off the filesystem. But to write files, you need the ability to write *and read* because without reading, you don't even know where you can write.

---

You could create an intelligent device that pretends to be an unencrypted USB storage device, but once something is written to it, it pretends to be disconnected, stores that data securely and reconnects pretending to be an empty storage device again. That would be quite complicated though.

Comment: Is there a specific region in the FAT system that stores filenames and locations?

Comment: I'm happy with the filenames and sizes visible as long as the content is hidden.

Comment: I agree with you that on file-system level write without read is not possible. But the question also contains the password only required for read and for saving data with password but read with password there are solutions like GnuPG (similar to sending encrypted e-mails). So in my opinion the question author has mixed up two distinct questions (password protection and write-only media) which do not belong together.

Comment: @Robert OP has a device that writes to standard microSD cards, but wants these cards to be unreadable without a password so that they can be safely left unattended. It must be a filesystem level solution because the device doesn't support anything but standard microSD with standard filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

You can format the USB partition with the Linux Uniform Keying System (LUKS), requiring a password to unlock for mounting and either reading or writing.

Comment: OP's requirement was to have it writable without any password.